# How to redirect individual page to website sub-domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Simple 301 is not working with this type of URL:

```
http://www.example.com/submit/action.php/?url=%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2F2017%2F10%2Ffacial-hair-trending-days.html%20&media=http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Screen-Shot-2017-10-13-at-5.05.59-PM.png
```

to

```
 subdomian.example.com/post-1
```

I have tried .htacess and wordpress plugin as well.

Comment: in wordpress header.php add `if` condition like `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'above url'){ redirection code}`

Comment: Tried this.. not working

Comment: it seems that url `/` converted to `%2F` so you need  to correct url before comparing

Comment: am sorry .. i am not understanding what r u saying..

Comment: please read my comment again. tru to use `urlencode()` or `urldecode()` there

Comment: sorry.. its by mistake..  have deleted the comment

Answer (score 1):

**URL Decode online:** 
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

**You have to use decoded URL in htaccess:**

http://www.example.com/submit/action.php/?url=http://www.example.com/2017/10/facial-hair-trending-days.html&media=http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Screen-Shot-2017-10-13-at-5.05.59-PM.png

**Note :** Remove space in URL.